# face an error with Build react-native-fbsdk

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

constructor FBSDKPackage in class FBSDKPackage
cannot be applied to given types;
             new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
             ^
  required: no arguments
  found: CallbackManager
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/429

have tried all solutions in the above link and still facing same issue

react-native: 0.59.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the latest version of react-native-fbsdk you will no longer to have pass the callbackManager to the constructor and the reason I strongly recommend you to upgrade it is that's the requirement of facebook to Upgrade to SDK v5.0 for new privacy features and the previous versions will stop working.

Comment: Thanks for your support. yes the issue was the versions compatibility i was on react-native @59.9 while i installed the latest update of fbsdk so i face the above issue but it's now solved :) :)